# Unexpected response code 500 for POST com.android.volley.ServerError Laravel backend

Tags: android, laravel, post, laravel-5, android-volley

My api is working fine bu I am getting Unexpected response code 500 error
when posting to the api using the following code:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                Log.i("TAG", "Response: " + response);
                            }

                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error:...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                        params.put("name", name);
                        params.put("address", address);
                        params.put("email", email);
                        return params;
                    }
                };
                MySingleton.getmInstance(MainActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
```

**Stacktrace:**
E/Volley: [258] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for url

Please tell me what I am missing here...

**EDIT 1:**

The previous error was due to a missing parameter and
As suggested by Anish I fixed the missing parameter.

But now its posting two times in the database and getting the error response as:  `BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500`

its retrying two times, post is success both times but the response is error 500,
Does anyone know how to fix this? I have **Laravel backend**

Comment: Could you post the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: Here is the stacktrace:

E/Volley: [258] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for url

Comment: have you tried making the request using any other tools like postman?

Comment: yes, I have tried. No error with postman

Comment: What does 500 mean?

Comment: @Dexter share a screenshot of the postman request

Comment: @greenapps Its the [HTTP code 500](https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html)

Comment: Yes of course. But what does it mean was the question.

Answer (score 1):

500 error is the error by internal server. Do check all the parameters and also the Request Method

Comment: Ya you were right one parameter was missing, but now its posting two times in the database and getting the error response as:  BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500,

its retrying two times, post is success both times but the response is error 500,
Do you know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `AndroidNetworking`? It is more easy to use.

eg.

first you need to gather your parameters to an `JSONObject` or `JSONArray` like this

```
 JSONObject params = new JSONObject();

    try {
        params.put("param0", value0);
        params.put("param1", value1);
        params.put("param2", value2);
        params.put("param3", value3);
```

And constructing will be like this. (The example that I've been given is an JSONObject)

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()      //<--- this is for the connection time out. if the device response is too long
            .connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    AndroidNetworking.initialize(getContext(), okHttpClient);
    AndroidNetworking.post(baseUrl + "endpoint")
            .addJSONObjectBody(params)
            .addHeaders("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .addHeaders("Prefer", "return=representation")
            .addHeaders("Accept", "application/vnd.pgrst.object+json") //<---- this part is for postgres database. you can remove it if you won't use it
            .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
            .build().getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.e("response EOD", String.valueOf(response));

            try {
                //your Statement here when the server has response

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                sendAndgetDispID();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(ANError anError) {
            try {
                //Log the error if there's any
                if (error.getErrorCode() != 0) {
                    Log.d("onError errorCode", "onError errorCode : " + error.getErrorCode());
                    Log.d("onError errorBody", "onError errorBody : " + error.getErrorBody());
                    Log.d("onError errorDetail", "onError errorDetail : " + error.getErrorDetail());

                } else {
                    Log.d("onError errorDetail", "onError errorDetail : " + error.getErrorDetail());
                }

            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        });
    } catch(Throwable e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Don't forget to declare this on your `build.gradle` module app

```
implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.1'
```